# jquery select2 - Retaining selected value on server validaton failure

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using jquery select2 (version 4.0) to load data dynamically from an API endpoint in a form.

When user submits the form and there are validation errors, the selected value in the select2 dropdown is wiped while the other inputs that don't use select2 retains the data user entered.

Is there a way I can preserve the user selected data on the form when server validation errors occur on the form?

HTML

```
<select id='selUser'>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#selUser").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a user",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: { 
        url: "/searchuser",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
              searchTerm: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        results: function (response) {
            return {
                results: response
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
 });
});
```